# how can i put where condition in where condition in SQL Query to check qty

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin, where-clause

i have table of lucky draw option where two types of option is there one is Stock Qty options and second option is General option

now i have to check the stock qty before i get the random option

i have write the query as below

```
set @percentage = 100 * rand();

select bkt_lucky_option.*,bkt_lucky_option_stock.option_stock_qty
from bkt_lucky_option LEFT JOIN bkt_lucky_option_stock ON bkt_lucky_option.lucky_option_id = bkt_lucky_option_stock.option_lucky_id
WHERE bkt_lucky_option_stock.option_stock_qty > 0
order by bkt_lucky_option.lucky_option_in_hour <= @percentage, rand()
limit 0, 8
```

**WHERE bkt_lucky_option_stock.option_stock_qty > 0**

For this condition i have to check if **lucky_option_type** is 1 then only i this condition should apply

Comment: Please add the tag for the DBMS do you use

Comment: how about lucky_option_type = 1 AND bkt_lucky_stock.option_stock_qty > 0 OR [your_other_conditions]?

Comment: So for one `bkt_lucky_option` you can have zero, one or many `bkt_lucky_option_stock`. And when `bkt_lucky_option.lucky_option_type = 1` you want to do what exactly? And when `bkt_lucky_option.lucky_option_type <> 1` you want to do what instead? Please show some sample data and expected results, so as to clarify what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE lucky_option_type != 1 OR bkt_lucky_option_stock.option_stock_qty > 0`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL server then try below query :

```
 SET @percentage = 100 * rand();

 SELECT bkt_lucky_option.*,bkt_lucky_option_stock.option_stock_qty
 FROM bkt_lucky_option 
 LEFT JOIN bkt_lucky_option_stock ON bkt_lucky_option.lucky_option_id = 
        bkt_lucky_option_stock.option_lucky_id
 WHERE ( bkt_lucky_option_stock.option_stock_qty > 0 AND lucky_option_type = 
         1 ) OR 
       ( bkt_lucky_option_stock.option_stock_qty = 
         bkt_lucky_option_stock.option_stock_qty AND lucky_option_type <> 1 
       )
 ORDER BY bkt_lucky_option.lucky_option_in_hour <= @percentage, RAND()
 limit 0, 8
```

Comment: He has PhpMyAdmin in his tags :p

Comment: Besides, your condition `bkt_lucky_option_stock.option_stock_qty = bkt_lucky_option_stock.option_stock_qty` can be replaced by `TRUE`.

Comment: @FabianPijcke, He not mentioned any other conditions other than lucky_option_type = 1,thats why I wrote that part